# Access text of a span in div via jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to change the text inside of a span tag in a Rails app.

```
<% @steps.each do |step| %>
  <div class="step_number">
    <span class="step_order_text"><%= step.order %></span>
  </div>              
<% end %>
```

I'd like to use a jQuery function to loop over all the 'step_order_text' classes which are created in the multiple steps, like so:

```
stepNums = $('.step_order_text');
    for(i in stepNums){
        var q = stepNums.get(i);
        q.text(updated_order[i].position);

    }
```

The problem is, I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: q.text is not a function
```

Any thoughts? Seems simple but I've been stuck on this for quite a while. Thank you in advance and hope everyone has a great weekend!

Comment: `q` is a DOM element. `text()` is a jQuery method, not a DOM method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.each()` to loop through a jQuery collection. Within the function body, `this` refers to the current element of the loop.

```
stepNums.each(function(i) {
    $(this).text(updated_order[i].position);
});
```

Comment: I had to make one small tweak: use 'toString()' instead of 'to_s'. Otherwise, worked perfectly and gave me a lesson that 'this' can be used in the loop. Thank you!

Comment: Your original code has `to_s`. Why is that wrong in my answer? When assigning to a string, `.toString()` will be called automatically, you don't need to do it explicitly.

Comment: Just wanted to make a note in case anyone looked at this. Thanks again.

Comment: I assumed `to_s` was a property you defined in your `position` objects.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken the *stepNums* variable will be a collection of DOM elements.

```
stepNums = $('.step_order_text');
for(i in stepNums){
    var q = $(stepNums.get(i));
    q.text(updated_order[i].position.to_s);

}
```

I believe this will fix your issue. Either wrapping each element in *$(..)* or using the alternative *innerText()* function

Comment: I see now about stepNums being a collection of DOMs. Thank you.